# How to add <a> tag in Angular based on condition

Tags: angular

How to add an `<a>` tag in Angular based on condition like

```html
{{(mockupSheet==0) ? "No" : <a href="SomeLinke">mockupSheetActualValue</a>}}
```

Comment: can you add your html file

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for *ngIF:

```html
<div *ngIf="mockupSheet!==0; else other">
    <a href="SomeLinke">mockupSheetActualValue</a>
</div>
<ng-template #other>
   No
</ng-template>
```

Comment: You're right; updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to display a template when the value returns `truthy`. You can use an [`else`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else) statement within the `*ngIf` attribute to display an alternative template if the `if` statement returns `falsy` value.

```html
<a href="SomeLinke" *ngIf="mockupSheet !== 0; else no">mockupSheetActualValue</a>

<ng-template #no>
  <span>No</span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngIf to show/hide depending on the given condition:

```
<div *ngIf="mockupSheet != 0; else noValue">
    <a href="SomeLinke">mockupSheetActualValue</a>
</div>

<ng-template #noValue>
    <a href="SomeLinke">No value</a>
</ng-template>
```